# ValidationExpression for a number that doesn't consisting of just zeros

Tags: javascript, regex

I have asp:RegularExpressionValidator and the ValidationExpression is "\d{0,9}"

My problem is that I can't get a number consisting of just zeros.

How can I check this kind of thing?

Thanks for the help

Comment: `"^(?!0{10})\d{0,9}$"` or `"^(?!0+$)\d{0,9}$"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you!  "^(?!0+$)\d{0,9}$" works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
/^[0]{0,9}$/
```